# renaming images in a folder - images deleted

Tags: php

I need to rename images in a folder i.e. give them unique names. Using this code images are not renamed but deleted !

```
$path = "../b-300x250/";
$items = glob($path . '*.jpg');
foreach($items as $img) { 
    $uniq = uniqid() . '.jpg';
    rename("$img", "$uniq");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is moving your images to a different directory.
Add the path to your unique name.

```
$path = "../b-300x250/";
$items = glob($path . '*.jpg');
foreach($items as $img) { 
    $uniq = $path . uniqid() . '.jpg';
    rename("$img", "$uniq");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you must provide complete path or a valid path. In your code you are trying to rename files in `current working directory` but actually you have to work on `../b-300x250/` directory, So you should append this to make your code to rename a file correctly.

**Change this:**

```
rename("$img", "$uniq");
```

**This:**

```
rename("$img", $path.$uniq);
```

**PHP code:**

```
$path = "../b-300x250/";
$items = glob($path . '*.jpg');
foreach ($items as $img)
{
    $uniq = uniqid() . '.jpg';
    rename("$img", $path.$uniq);
}
```